pip install pyqt5 (no traceback just "Killed")
I'm trying to install PyQtWebEngine on an Ubuntu 22.0 ARM VM running under UTF on a MacBook M3 Max.  I've searched multiple stack overflow and other pages and I'm stuck.
What I've done:
pip install --upgrade pip
sudo apt install qt5-default
pip install pyqt5-sip
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev qtchooser qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools
sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev

What I get:
dean@ubuntu:~$ pip install pyqt5
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.11.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... -Killed

VM Specs:
Ubuntu 22.04
8GB, 4 Cores, 32GB disk (47% free)
Host Specs
Macbook M3 Max 96 GB Ram

Just "Killed" means not enough RAM. "VM Specs: Ubuntu 22.04 8GB" It seems 8GB is not enough.

upped to 32 GB. olnly two python process seems to be running. But still Killed. I used free to watch the ram and it kept consuming more ram. So there is some sort of memory leak

There're very few precompiled wheels available: https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/5.15.11/#files so pip is trying to compile from sources and that's darn hard, I suspect. In addition to increasing RAM also increase disk space, create a swapfile (recommended size = 4 * RAM) and activate it with swapon.

Also note that when installing PyQt from pip, it will always use its own Qt build (eventually forcing a full Qt compile on certain architectures, which requires a lot of time and disk space). This means that: 1. unless you use other Qt programs, installing qt based packages with apt would be pointless (and waste of space); 2. installing pyqt related packages with apt would be similarly pointless (and could create inconsistencies). Basically, if the distribution provides updated and prebuilt packages (and they're properly maintained), you should always try use them to begin with.

Thanks. That seems to have worked. Using apt to find the equivalent packages got me where I wanted.
